# Can I use the same CKServerChangeToken for multiple subscriptions?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have two subscriptions on the same record type `List`: the first one for the creation of records of type `List` with a reference to a record `A` and the second one for the creation of records of type `List` with a reference to a record `B`.

I'm using silent notifications with `CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation` to don't miss an update. The main problem is how to use `CKServerChangeToken`: should I use two tokens depending on the subscription or is using just one token for all the subscriptions on a record type (in that case `List`) working?